# Do the uses of 'on the left' and 'to the left' depend on how close the two objects are?

Tags: prepositions

Does whether 'on' or 'to' should be used depend on how close the two objects are?
For example, I can use 'to' and say that to the north of the information desk area is a lecture room because the two sections are so close to each other. (I understand using 'north' is a bad idea because there is no compass on the diagram. I'm just using it to learn prepositions.)

What about the reference book section that is one pathway away? Should 'to' or 'on' be used?

> **To/On** the left side of the information desk area, the space that used to contain adult fiction books now accommodates reference books.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on context. If I were standing at the end of the information desk I could point out to you

> **To** the right are the self service machines and the Cafe whilst **to** the
> left are the adult loan books and the lecture room.

but I could equally say

> **On** the right are the self service machines and the Cafe whilst **on** the
> left are the adult loan books and the lecture room.

but if I were giving directions from the entrance I could only say

> Walk up the passage and turn **to** your right for the information desk.

> turn **on** your right

doesn't make sense.
In general **on** signifies a place (**on** the right or **on** the left) whilst **to** can also be a direction, turn **to** the North or turn **to** your right for example. The distance of the place or object is not normally relevant, but if describing place I would prefer to use **to** for thing at a distance (for example, in the middle of the Mediterranean sea I would say Europe is **to** the North and Africa **to** the South. I would use either for things nearby - thing I can see.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. About your sentence 'Walk up the passage and turn to your right for the information desk', can I use either 'on' or 'to' if I write like this: Walking up the passage, **on/to** the right is the information desk?

Comment: Yes, **to or on** both work. It's worth noting that you could say either *walk up the passage*, *or walk down the passage*. Again, both have the same meaning in this context, but not all. *Walk up the hill* is the opposite of *walk down the hill*.